# Approximating weight of individual items from sum of their weight

Tags: linear-regression

### Problem

I have a list of orders, approximation of their total weight and list of items they contain. I need to determine approximate weight of individual items.

In other words, I have a few thousand of equations like these:
$$
\begin{cases}
    3x_{110} ~+ & x_{242} ~+ &5x_{412} = 82.5 \\
    8x_{784} ~+ &4x_{124} ~+ &2x_{872} = 49.2 \\
    1x_{784} ~+ & x_{124} ~+ &x_{847} = 120.2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
And I need to find approximate values of $x$, such that the sum of squared errors would be minimal. It seems to me like my problem is a Matrix formulation of Ordinary least squares. Is this correct?

May I ask for advice on how to **practically** calculate this for thousands of equations with thousands of variables?

#### What I've tried

- I've tried using [solver in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040), but that didn't work because it's limited to 200 variables.
- I've tried generating [the equations in GNU MathProg](https://pastebin.pl/view/30f49174) and using an [online solver](https://online-optimizer.appspot.com/), but the results don't seem to be accurate enough, as this solver supports only strictly linear equations (i.e. no absolute value, no squared errors).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem. However, if you want to try a linear regression on this you can simply arrange all the $x$ in a matrix. Say you have (I try to immitate your notation):

$$ 80.3 = 3 x_2 + 9 x_3 \\
 72.5 = 5 x_1 + 7 x_3 \\
68.8 = 2x_2 + 9x_3$$

This would yield a $y$ vector and $X$ matrix like:

$\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
80.3 \\ 
72.5 \\
68.8 \\ 
\end{array}\right)$ = $\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 3 & 9 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 7 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}\right)$

Note the first column is equal to 1 for each row. This is the intercept term ($\beta_0$) in the regression model below.

The aim is to find individual weights for each $x$ which best matches the outcome $y$. So the model (omitting subscripts) is:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + u$$

Now you can solve for $\beta$ using matrix algebra:

$$ (X'X)^{-1}X'y = \hat{\beta}$$

You need more "rows" (observations) than columns ($x$) to solve this with ordinary least squares (OLS, aka "linear regression").

Free [software like `R`](https://www.r-project.org/) can easily do a linear regression.

**Example in `R` with dummy data:**

```
df = data.frame(y=c(80.3,72.5,68.8,75.3,23.6), x1=c(0,5,0,2,0), x2=c(3,0,2,1,1), x3=c(9,7,9,3,5))
```

Data looks like (you can of course load Excel files etc in `R`):

```
     y x1 x2 x3
1 80.3  0  3  9
2 72.5  5  0  7
3 68.8  0  2  9
4 75.3  2  1  3
5 23.6  0  1  5
```

Now do a linear regression:

```
summary(lm(y~.,data=df))
```

The result will be:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   11.299     30.552   0.370    0.774
x1            15.714      7.641   2.057    0.288
x2            31.812     17.426   1.826    0.319
x3            -2.081      4.890  -0.426    0.744

Residual standard error: 18.92 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8311,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3246 
F-statistic: 1.641 on 3 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.5081
```

You can calculate the (estimated) $\hat{y}$ for the first row like:

```
11.299 + 15.714 * 0 + 31.812 * 3 - 2.081 * 9
```

Which gives: `88.006`